# restrict a setter to a static list of values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following models

```
public class CustomEvent
{
    private string _tag;
    

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Mentor { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Tag         
    {
        get => _tag;
        set 
            {
                _tag = GetTagTypeList.GetTagType(typeof(TagType)).Contains(value) ? value : "Unspecified";
            }
    }
}



public static class TagType
{
    public const string Unspecified = "Unspecified";
    public const string AmxPersonalItemCreate = "Amx.PersonalItem.Create";
    public const string AmxPersonalItemUpdate = "Amx.PersonalItem.Update";
    public const string AmxPersonalItemDelete = "Amx.PersonalItem.Delete";
    public const string AmxRegionCreate = "Amx.Region.Create";
    public const string AmxRegionUpdate = "Amx.Region.Delete";
    public const string AmxRegionDelete = "Amx.Region.Update";
}

public  class GetTagTypeList
{
    public static List<String> GetTagType(Type type)
    {
        return  type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                .Select(x=>x.GetValue(null).ToString()).ToList();
    }
}
```

The above code restricts the setter to the list of static values. However this is very inefficient, as it is reflecting over the class every single time the method [GetTagType] is called.

I now have a requirement to Create a TagType class with a private constructor, and static values.

Given the values to be expressed have "." in them, it will require a custom json serializer as well.

I have read somewhere that a solution could be to use nested classes to get values which match the string being created.

i.e. for "Amx.PersonalItem.Create" we could create a class which resemble:

```
public static class Amx
{
    public static class PersonalItem
    {
        public static TagType Create { get; } = new TagType("Amx.PersonalItem.Create");
    }
}
```

I need to integrate the above example into my CustomEvent Class.
Or any other solution that uses static values to achieve same result.
Would appreciate any help ?

Comment: So, is the only `List<String>` that `GetTagType` is every going to return are the strings between the value of `Unspecified` and `AmxRegionDelete` in the `TagType` class?  All you need to do is pre-compute the list, maybe with as a static `Lazy<T>`.  That's basically what @LorenPechtel` is proposing.  To do that, create a static `Lazy<List<string>>`, with a constructor expression that runs your current reflection code.  Anytime you need the list, just pull up the Lazy's `Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making a static item in the class that builds the list and stores it in a static variable?  That means you can build the list once no matter how many times your setter is called.  You still have to search the list but you don't need to use reflection.

Comment: Can you put your example here please ?

Comment: Or build a `MemoryCache` that contains `List<string>` entries that are accessed by `Type` (or perhaps type name - strings can make debugging easier). That way, you don't keep everything forever (the cache may discard older entries), but recent entries should be available in the cache. Using a cache like that is a pretty common pattern - you should be able to find examples.  Basically, your `GetTagType` would look in the cache first. If it finds a hit it returns it.  If not, it does the Reflection work, caches the result and then returns that result

Comment: @Flydog57 Given the apparent size of his list that's overkill.  There's also the issue that you can only read the whole list, you can't replace one item tossed out of the cache.

Comment: Could be - I get lost in his question about 2/3 of the way in, right around _"I now have a requirement to Create a TagType class with a private constructor, and static values"_.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yeah, I'm thinking this is homework.

Comment: @Flydog57 the example I gave above defines having a private constructor and static values
 Also access to this value would be
    var TagType = Amx.PersonaIItem.Create